# how to add xml child node with namespace in python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

i'm realy stuck in this, i got a file with an xml layout like this:

```
<rss xmlns:irc="SomeName" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <irc:title>A title</irc:title>
            <irc:poster>A poster</irc:poster>
            <irc:url>An url</irc:url>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

i need to add another  'item' in channel node, that's easy, but i can't find the way to add the item's child with the namespace.

i'm trying with lxml, but the documentation is not so clear for a newbie
please any help will be appreciated.

---

i find the way to doit with lxml

```
root = xml.getroot()
channel = root.find('channel')
item = et.Element('item')
title = et.SubElement(item,'{SomeName}title')
title.text = 'My new title'
poster = et.SubElement(item,'{SomeName}poster')
poster.text = 'My poster'
poster = et.SubElement(item,'{SomeName}url')
poster.text = 'http://My.url.com'
channel.append(item)
```

but still interested in a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), the declarative programming language, that transforms, styles, re-formats, and re-structures XML files in any way, shape, or form. Python's lxml module maintains an XSLT processor.

Simply, register the needed namespace in the XSLT's declaration line and use it in any new node. This might appear to be overkill for your current need but there could be a situation where a more complex transformation is needed with appropriate namespaces. Below adds a new title to the previous poster and URL.

**XSLT** (to be saved as .xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:irc="SomeName">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>      

<xsl:template match="rss">
  <rss>   
    <channel>
      <xsl:for-each select="//item">
        <item>
          <irc:title>My new title</irc:title>
          <xsl:copy-of select="irc:poster"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="irc:url"/>       
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </channel>
  </rss>
 </xsl:template> 

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python**

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

# SET CURRENT DIRECTORY
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# LOAD IN XML AND XSL FILES
dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Original.xml'))
xslt = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'XSLT_Script.xsl'))

# TRANSFORM
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUT FINAL XML
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'output.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:irc="SomeName">
   <channel>
      <item>
         <irc:title>My new title</irc:title>
         <irc:poster>A poster</irc:poster>
         <irc:url>An url</irc:url>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: i like your method, because i try every way a found to correctly indent the output with lxml and none of them works, i currently use tidylib to do that.